# How do you use GSL's Cholesky Decomposition function with C

Tags: c, gsl

I've been using GSL to support some matrix manipulation using C.  I'm having a challenge with its Cholesky Decomposition function though and the documentation in the GSL reference manual is sparse to say the least.  How do I get the Lower Triangular matrix output of the function?

Below is my code so far ...

```
# include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
# include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
#define rows 6
#define cols 6

double cov[rows*cols] = {107.3461, 12.0710, -48.3746, 174.7796, 21.0202, -80.6075,
                12.0710, 8.0304, -5.9610, 20.2434, 2.2427, -9.312,
                -48.3746, -5.9610, 25.2222, -78.6277, -9.4400, 36.1789,
                174.7796, 20.2434, -78.6277, 291.3491, 35.0176, -134.3626,
                21.0202, 2.2427, -9.4400, 35.0176, 4.2144, -16.1499,
                -80.6075, -9.3129, 36.1789, -134.3626, -16.1499, 61.9666};

gsl_matrix_view m = gsl_matrix_view_array(cov, rows, cols);

int gsl_linalg_cholesky_decomp1(gsl_matrix *m)

... don't know what to do after this step
```

I know the formulas for calculating this manually, but I'd prefer to take advantage of this library instead.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: GSL [LU Decomp Example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/linalg.html#examples) seems right on point.

Answer (score 0):

Got things to work right with David's suggestion and a bit more digging ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

int main ()
{

    double cov[9] = {2, -1, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, -1, 2};

    gsl_matrix_view m = gsl_matrix_view_array(cov, 3, 3);
    gsl_matrix *x = gsl_matrix_alloc(3,3);

    gsl_linalg_cholesky_decomp1(&m.matrix);

    printf ("x = \n");
    gsl_matrix_fprintf (stdout, x, "%g");
}
```